# How to apply a formula to an entire sheet for every row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a problem applying a formula to an excel sheet.

I need to pick an entire row and change it's color depending on the value of the cell "E" in that row. This rule should apply to the entire sheet.

So, if I'm in row 3 and E3 is greater than 0, the entire row should be green. If I'm in row 7 and E7 is greater than 0, the entire row should be green, and so on...

If I use this formula: =($E:$E)>0 for $1:$1048576 range, it changes de color for all cells in the entire sheet using only cell E1 value

How can I do this? I'd appreciate your help

Comment: `=$E1>0` and apply the rule to the entire sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so simple... That solved it